# Move files in different folders but exclude one subfolder in each folder

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to change a Powershell script so it can move some files but exclude specific subfolders, but can't seem to get it right.

First the script uploads some file structure to an FTP - that one works. But when the files are uploaded, I want them to be moved on the source to an Uploaded folder. That way I can control, that the files aren't uploaded again, as I exclude the uploaded folder.

The file structure is as following. The files are located in both PurchOrderNavn and both PurchPackingSlipNav, and when they are uploaded to the FTP, I need to move them to the Uploaded folder.

[image: file structure1]

My upload script are there, and as you can see I was thinking about making the move in the finally part, but again not sure how that is done. Perhaps it's easier another way around.

```
# Put network share into array
$localePathArray = @(
    "\\network share\Optimate"
)
# Put FTP share into array
$remotePathArray = @(
    "/Optimate/"
)
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"

# Session.FileTransferred event handler


function FileTransferred
{
param($e)


if ($e.Error -eq $Null)
{
    Write-Host "Upload of $($e.FileName) succeeded"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Upload of $($e.FileName) failed: $($e.Error)"
}

if ($e.Chmod -ne $Null)
{
    if ($e.Chmod.Error -eq $Null)
    {
        Write-Host "Permissions of $($e.Chmod.FileName) set to $($e.Chmod.FilePermissions)"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Setting permissions of $($e.Chmod.FileName) failed: $($e.Chmod.Error)"
    }

}
else
{
    Write-Host "Permissions of $($e.Destination) kept with their defaults"
}

if ($e.Touch -ne $Null)
{
    if ($e.Touch.Error -eq $Null)
    {
        Write-Host "Timestamp of $($e.Touch.FileName) set to $($e.Touch.LastWriteTime)"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Setting timestamp of $($e.Touch.FileName) failed: $($e.Touch.Error)"
    }

}
else
{
    # This should never happen during "local to remote" synchronization
    Write-Host "Timestamp of $($e.Destination) kept with its default (current time)"
}
}

 # Main script

 try
 {


  # Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
HostName = "ip address"
PortNumber = 21
UserName = "username"
Password = "password"
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

$TransferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions 
$TransferOptions.FileMask = "|*/Uploaded/" #uploader filer og mapper, og sletter dem som ikke findes, undtaget sync files
#$TransferOptions.FileMask = "null" #Filtrer intet fra, så alt i mapperne uploades

try
{

# Will continuously report progress of synchronization
$session.add_FileTransferred( { FileTransferred($_) } )

#Logging
$session.SessionLogPath = "C:\scripts\FTP\logs\Nav sync.log"

# Connect
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

# Synchronize files
for ($i=0; $i -lt $localePathArray.length; $i++) {
   # Write-Host "$localePathArray[$i] $remotePathArray[$i]"

    #$synchronizationResult = $session.SynchronizeDirectories([WinSCP.SynchronizationMode]::Remote, 
    $localePathArray[$i], $remotePathArray[$i], $True, $False, [WinSCP.SynchronizationCriteria]::Time, $TransferOptions) #$true sletter filer fra ftp, som er blevet slettet på filserver, sæt den til $False hvis dette ikke ønskes
    $synchronizationResult = $session.SynchronizeDirectories([WinSCP.SynchronizationMode]::Remote, 
    $localePathArray[$i], $remotePathArray[$i], $False, $False, [WinSCP.SynchronizationCriteria]::Time, $TransferOptions) #$true sletter filer fra ftp, som er blevet slettet på filserver, sæt den til $False hvis dette ikke ønskes
   }

# Throw on any error
$synchronizationResult.Check()

}
finally
{
$session.Dispose()

# Move uploaded files

}
exit 0
}
catch
{
Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
exit 1
}
```

Comment: See [Copy files to FTP and archive with today's date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47473578/850848) or [PowerShell script to copy files but not subfolders to SFTP and move to subfolder once done](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58758410/850848).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy files to FTP and archive with today's date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473578/copy-files-to-ftp-and-archive-with-todays-date)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Hi, finally got a chance to look at your links, but I don't think they will help me a lot. Me problem is, that the upload-function starts at the top level, but I need to move files on a subfolder level. My problem is that I don't know how I should get hold of the files, just after they are being uploaded. I could create a task for each subfolder, but why have x numbers of tasks if its possible to have only one?

Comment: Imo, that's exactly what the links show. See the `foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)` loop in [Copy files to FTP and archive with today's date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47473578/850848#47473909).

Comment: Yep, you're right. I had to rewrite it a bit, but most of it was because I didn't catch it the first time I looked at it. Can you put in an answer with the link, so you can get due credit for this?

Comment: Please accept that your question is duplicate and consider upvoting the linked question and its (my) answer. Thanks.